# Identify if a click is within borders of a div when a Child div overflows

Tags: jquery, click

I have two divs one within the other. The Child div overflows.

```
<div id="dv1">
    <p> hello world</p>
    <div class="child1">Inner Div</div>
</div>
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/Sq7hg/629/

Is it possible to find out if I click within the green border of parent div, including parts of the child div which is inside the border?

Comment: ... but excluding the portion of the parent element not covered by the child?

Comment: @isherwood No, All of Parent Div (yellow area) including the portion covered by the child (red) inside the green borders. Exclude the portion of child which is outside the green border.

Comment: In that case, I'm not clear why you can just do a click event on the parent div.

Comment: @isherwood Problem being if I click on child divs which are overflowing out of the parent div, the event still triggers as clicked within the parent Div. I dont want that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For readiblity I took out some of your code.

In any case if it fails that 'test' you can just return or have it act differently.

Here is it in action: http://jsbin.com/qerud/10/edit

```
$(function() {


    function validateClick (elem,e){
        /*Gets clicked position inside the element */
        var posX = e.pageX - elem.position().left,
            posY = e.pageY - elem.position().top;

        /* Compares click to the size of the element */
        var elemWidth = elem.width();
        elemHeight = elem.height();

        if(elemWidth > posX && elemHeight > posY){
            return true;
        }
            return false;

    };


    $("#dv1").mousedown(function(e) {
        $(this).css('background-color','yellow');
        if(!validateClick($(this),e)){
            return $(this).css('background-color','blue');
        }

    });
```

});

Comment: I'm actually rethinking, I'm not sure if the border logic is even needed...  If you find this useful I'll look back at it.

Comment: very cool. Thanks, and you are right. border logic is not really important. it works! :)

Comment: Cool I edited the answer to not include it.  Good luck!